Add headers to request while using AWS API Gateway generated SDK
I have a Java SDK generated for my API Gateway REST API following the official guide Generate the Java SDK of an API in API Gateway. A client is connecting to my API Gateway via VPC endpoint and it requires Host header to be present. However, there does not seem to be an easy way to add a custom header to the request using the generated SDK. Am I missing something trivial here?
